# How to keep Model consistent when saving via service?

Tags: wpf, wcf, oop, mvvm, synchronization

I am working on a client/server (WPF/WCF) application using the MVVM pattern.

Properties on the ViewModel are bound to properties on the Model such that when the Model is changed, the change is propagated immediately to the View.

When the user clicks refresh, any new/changed data on the server is merged into Model, so the refresh mechanism is working well.

How do I handle the user editing and saving properties?  Here is what I want to happen:

> 1. User clicks "Edit"
> 2. User modifies values in TextBoxes
> 3. User clicks "Save"
> 4. Changes are sent to server
> 5. If successful, server returns updated item, which is merged into
>      Model, and the UI is updated.
> 6. If not successful, server returns error and Model is not updated.

It seems that by using MVVM, the Model is updated at step 3 (making steps 5 & 6 redundant), and if an error occurs on the server, data at the client becomes inconsistent with the server.

*Is there a best practice way to deal with this situation?*

Comment: In your scenario, is it possible for data on the server to go out of sync with a specific client, without the client having to do anything?  Will that ever be possible in the future?  The reason I ask is that you may require a syncing strategy that doesn't require the user to restart the app/manually refresh.  A problem like this might neatly fit within that strategy.  You might simply do a sync after every save, good or not.

Comment: Yes - it is a multi-user app, but a refresh happens whenever the user views an item so that the client is up to date.  What you suggest makes sense, but what happens if the server is down when the user clicks Save?  I would like for the original values to be restored (possibly transitioning to offline mode).

Comment: Part of the the problem is that your webservice *is* the model.  The remote and local copies are both representations of the same thing.  If you can't update the model remotely, then you *should* update the model locally, and do whatever you need to do to cope with them going out of sync.  "a refresh happens whenever the user views an item".  What if it gets updated while they're viewing it?  You should figure out how to handle this case, lest one user accidentally undo another user's changes, simply because they happened to have the dialog open.

Comment: The new/changed data gets merged into the Model, which propagates to the View.

Comment: Actually I take part of that back.  The web service is definitely part of the model, and somehow has to get synced with the local model.  But there's no clear-cut advice on what to do on a failed save, nor what your exact syncing strategy should be.  There is certainly no industry standard that I know of, and I've seen different behavior in many apps.

Comment: One thing that may help with your design, though, is not trying to make your ViewModel and Model look the same.  You could use a similar interface for your web service as you do for your model - basically, a DAL type interface.  You can still use events to tell the ViewModel that Refresh needs to be called, but you won't implement INotifyPropertyChanged like you would in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice, but I've already dealt with the issues you have identified and am more interested in the use case presented in the question.

Comment: @Greg: No problem.  If it isn't helpful, it isn't helpful, hence why it isn't an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have come up with is to create a second set of objects - ModelUpdates.

When the user clicks *Edit*, a ModelUpdate object (which has the same properties as the Model object) is instantiated and the DataContext is switched to that object.

When the user clicks *Save*, details of the ModelUpdate object are sent to the service.  The service responds with details about the updated object, which are then merged into the Model repository.

This means that the Model is only ever updated with data that has been successfully saved.  If the object was saved incorrectly, the database version will be sent back to the client.  If an error occurred in saving, the database version will be sent back to the client. If the server is unavailable, the client will keep the pre-edit version.

Answer (score 0):

The way we have handled this stored a copy of original data. 
Whenever an update fails, we restored the original data to the view.

Comment: This will work if the programmers always account for it in their error handling.  I'm looking for an architectural solution which takes the onus away from individual programmers.

Answer (score -1):

I think a synchronous post method should be used.
This way, if an error occurs, the model and the view side are the same. Also, your view won't be updated until it get's the saved data back.

In simple words:

1) User clicks edit
2) User makes changes
3) User clicks save
3.1) Application sumbits the data to the model
3.2) Model saves changes
3.3) Model returns changed data
4) View changes with a succes (changed data) or failed message.

Comment: Thanks @Erik, but your solution still has the problem I am trying to avoid - if the save fails, the model contains bad data.